# Maze Constructor Issues [Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8)]

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, llvm

When I run my program, everything compiles until the `Maze` class is instantiated. I get a warning saying `Code will never be executed` in my 
main.cpp. The compiler (Xcode) redirects me to `The LLVM Compiler Infrastructure`, where on `line 1590` it says `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8)`. The block of code where this is indicated is:

```
template <class _Tp, class _Allocator>
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
void
vector<_Tp, _Allocator>::push_back(const_reference __x)
{
    if (this->__end_ != this->__end_cap()) //Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8)
    {
        __RAII_IncreaseAnnotator __annotator(*this);
        __alloc_traits::construct(this->__alloc(),
                                  _VSTD::__to_raw_pointer(this->__end_), __x);
        __annotator.__done();
        ++this->__end_;
    }
    else
        __push_back_slow_path(__x);
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "Maze.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "-------------\tMaze\t-------------\n\n";

    Maze maze(10);
    std::string direction;

    while(!true)
    {
        //Code will never be executed warning HERE
        std::cout << "Input a character to move your avatar in the maze and press RETURN\n";
        std::cout << "(w = UP, s = DOWN, a = LEFT, d = RIGHT)\n";
        std::cin >> direction;
        maze.takeTurn(direction);
        maze.printMe();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My header file:

```
#ifndef MAZE_H
#define MAZE_H

#include <vector>
#include <string>

extern const std::string Up;
extern const std::string Down;
extern const std::string Left;
extern const std::string Right;

class Maze
{
private:
    char avatarToken; //character that represents the avatar
    char emptyToken; //character that represents empty space in the maze
    char wallToken; //character that represents a wall
    char exitToken; //character that represents an exit - where you quit the game
    char stairsUpToken; //character that represents stairs that take you to an UPPER level
    char stairsDownToken; //character that represents a Hole that takes you a LOWER level
    char bossToken; //character that represents a boss that kills you (you lose/exit the game)

    int dim; //width of this square maze
    std::vector< std::vector<char> > grid; //a vector of vectors of characters

    int avatarRow; //row position of our avatar from zero to dim-1 (NOT from 1 to dim)
    int avatarCol; //column position of our avatar from zero to dim-1 (NOT from 1 to dim)

public:
    //constructor
    Maze(int newDim = 4,
         char _avatarToken = 'A',
         char _emptyToken = ' ',
         char _wallToken = '*',
         char _exitToken = 'E',
         char _stairsUpToken = '^',
         char _stairsDownToken = 'V',
         char _bossToken = 'B');

    void printMe();
    bool takeTurn(std::string direction); //move the avatar in the requested direction if possible
};

#endif
```

My implementation file:

```
#include "Maze.h"
#include "Keyboard.h" //contains global variables: Up, Down, Left, Right
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

//1st constructor
Maze::Maze(int newDim,
           char _avatarToken,
           char _emptyToken,
           char _wallToken,
           char _exitToken,
           char _stairsUpToken,
           char _stairsDownToken,
           char _bossToken) : dim(newDim),
                              avatarToken(_avatarToken),
                              emptyToken(_emptyToken),
                              wallToken(_wallToken),
                              exitToken(_exitToken),
                              stairsUpToken(_stairsUpToken),
                              stairsDownToken(_stairsDownToken),
                              bossToken(_bossToken)
{
    //place avatar location in center of maze
    this->avatarRow = newDim / 2;
    this->avatarCol = newDim / 2;

    //initialize top wall of grid
    for(int i = 0; i < this->dim; i++)
        this->grid[0].push_back(this->wallToken);

    //initialize middle of grid
    for(int j = 1; j < this->dim - 1; j++)
        for(std::vector<char>::iterator it = this->grid[j].begin(); it < this->grid[j].end(); it++)
            it == this->grid[j].begin() ||
            it == this->grid[j].end() ? this->grid[j].push_back(this->wallToken) :
            this->grid[j].push_back(this->emptyToken);

    //initialize bottom wall of grid
    for(int l = 0; l < this->dim; l++)
        this->grid[dim - 1].push_back(this->wallToken);

    //place exit token in random spot in the maze
    srand( (unsigned int) time(0)); //random seed for exit token placement in maze
    int rand_wall = rand() % 4 + 1; //determine which wall exit token is on
    int rand_placement = rand() % this->dim + 1; //placement of exit on wall
    switch(rand_wall)
    {
        case 1:
            this->grid[0][rand_placement] = this->exitToken;
            break;
        case 2:
            this->grid[rand_placement][0] = this->exitToken;
            break;
        case 3:
            this->grid[this->dim - 1][rand_placement] = this->exitToken;
            break;
        case 4:
            this->grid[rand_placement][this->dim - 1] = this->exitToken;
            break;
    }

    //place stairs up token in random spot in the maze
    srand( (unsigned int) time(0)); //random seed for stairs up token placement in maze
    rand_wall = rand() % 4 + 1; //determine which wall stairs up token is on
    rand_placement = rand() % this->dim + 1; //placement of stairs up on wall
    switch(rand_wall)
    {
        case 1:
            //check to see if element is occupied by exit token
            if(this->grid[0][rand_placement] != this->exitToken)
                this->grid[0][rand_placement] = this->stairsUpToken;
            break;
        case 2:
            //check to see if element is occupied by exit token
            if(this->grid[rand_placement][0] != this->exitToken)
                this->grid[rand_placement][0] = this->stairsUpToken;
            break;
        case 3:
            //check to see if element is occupied by exit token
            if(this->grid[this->dim - 1][rand_placement] != this->exitToken)
                this->grid[this->dim - 1][rand_placement] = this->stairsUpToken;
            break;
        case 4:
            //check to see if element is occupied by exit token
            if(this->grid[rand_placement][this->dim - 1] != this->exitToken)
                this->grid[rand_placement][this->dim - 1] = this->stairsUpToken;
            break;
    }

    //place stairs down token in random spot in the maze
    srand( (unsigned int) time(0)); //random seed for stairs down token placement in maze
    rand_wall = rand() % 4 + 1; //determine which wall stairs down token is on
    rand_placement = rand() % this->dim; //placement of stairs down on wall
    switch(rand_wall)
    {
        case 1:
            //check to see if element is occupied by exit token or stairs up token
            if(this->grid[0][rand_placement] != this->exitToken ||
               this->grid[0][rand_placement] != this->stairsUpToken)
            {
                this->grid[0][rand_placement] = this->stairsDownToken;
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            //check to see if element is occupied by exit token or stairs up token
            if(this->grid[rand_placement][0] != exitToken ||
               this->grid[rand_placement][0] != this->stairsUpToken)
            {
                this->grid[rand_placement][0] = this->stairsDownToken;
            }
            break;

        case 3:
            //check to see if element is occupied by exit token or stairs up token
            if(this->grid[this->dim - 1][rand_placement] != this->exitToken ||
               this->grid[this->dim - 1][rand_placement] != this->stairsUpToken)
            {
                this->grid[this->dim - 1][rand_placement] = this->stairsDownToken;
            }
            break;

        case 4:
            //check to see if element is occupied by exit token or stairs up token
            if(this->grid[rand_placement][this->dim - 1] != this->exitToken ||
               this->grid[rand_placement][this->dim - 1] != this->stairsUpToken)
            {
                this->grid[rand_placement][this->dim - 1] = this->stairsDownToken;
            }
            break;
    }

    //place boss token in random spot inside the maze
    srand( (unsigned int) time(0)); //random seed for boss token placement in maze
    rand_placement = rand() % this->dim; //placement of boss token
    switch(rand_wall)
    {
        case 1:
            //check to see if element is occupied by exit token or stairs up token
            if(this->grid[0][rand_placement] != this->exitToken ||
               this->grid[0][rand_placement] != this->stairsUpToken)
            {
                this->grid[0][rand_placement] = this->stairsDownToken;
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            //check to see if element is occupied by exit token or stairs up token
            if(this->grid[rand_placement][0] != exitToken ||
               this->grid[rand_placement][0] != this->stairsUpToken)
            {
                this->grid[rand_placement][0] = this->stairsDownToken;
            }
            break;

        case 3:
            //check to see if element is occupied by exit token or stairs up token
            if(this->grid[this->dim - 1][rand_placement] != this->exitToken ||
               this->grid[this->dim - 1][rand_placement] != this->stairsUpToken)
            {
                this->grid[this->dim - 1][rand_placement] = this->stairsDownToken;
            }
            break;

        case 4:
            //check to see if element is occupied by exit token or stairs up token
            if(this->grid[rand_placement][this->dim - 1] != this->exitToken ||
               this->grid[rand_placement][this->dim - 1] != this->stairsUpToken)
            {
                this->grid[rand_placement][this->dim - 1] = this->stairsDownToken;
            }
            break;
    }
}

//print maze row by row
void Maze::printMe()
{
    //rows
    for(int m = 0; m < this->dim; m++)
    {
        //columns
        for(int n = 0; n < this->dim; n++)
        {
            //print avatar token
            if(m == this->avatarRow && n == this->avatarCol)
                std::cout << this->avatarToken;
            else
                std::cout << this->grid[m][n];
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

//update location of the avatar
bool Maze::takeTurn(std::string _direction)
{
    if(_direction == Up && this->grid[this->avatarRow - 1][this->avatarCol] != this->wallToken)
    {
        --this->avatarRow;
        if(this->grid[this->avatarRow - 1][this->avatarCol] == this->exitToken ||
           this->grid[this->avatarRow - 1][this->avatarCol] == this->bossToken ||
           this->grid[this->avatarRow - 1][this->avatarCol] == this->stairsUpToken ||
           this->grid[this->avatarRow - 1][this->avatarCol] == this->stairsDownToken)
        {
            std::cout << "You exited the maze.\n";
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }
    else if(_direction == Down && this->grid[this->avatarRow + 1][this->avatarCol] != this->wallToken)
    {
        ++this->avatarRow;
        if(this->grid[this->avatarRow + 1][this->avatarCol] == this->exitToken ||
           this->grid[this->avatarRow + 1][this->avatarCol] == this->bossToken ||
           this->grid[this->avatarRow + 1][this->avatarCol] == this->stairsUpToken ||
           this->grid[this->avatarRow + 1][this->avatarCol] == this->stairsDownToken)
        {
            std::cout << "You exited the maze.\n";
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }
    else if(_direction == Left && this->grid[this->avatarRow][this->avatarCol - 1] != this->wallToken)
    {
        --this->avatarCol;
        if(this->grid[this->avatarRow][this->avatarCol - 1] != this->exitToken ||
           this->grid[this->avatarRow][this->avatarCol - 1] != this->bossToken ||
           this->grid[this->avatarRow][this->avatarCol - 1] != this->stairsUpToken ||
           this->grid[this->avatarRow][this->avatarCol - 1] != this->stairsDownToken)
        {
            std::cout << "You exited the maze.\n";
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }
    else if(_direction == Right && this->grid[this->avatarRow][this->avatarCol + 1] != this->wallToken)
    {
        ++this->avatarCol;
        if(this->grid[this->avatarRow][this->avatarCol + 1] != this->exitToken ||
           this->grid[this->avatarRow][this->avatarCol + 1] != this->bossToken ||
           this->grid[this->avatarRow][this->avatarCol + 1] != this->stairsUpToken ||
           this->grid[this->avatarRow][this->avatarCol + 1] != this->stairsDownToken)
        {
            std::cout << "You exited the maze.\n";
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    else return false;
}
```

EDIT: Removed unnecessary class member from `class Maze`.

Comment: Not the reason for the bad access but look closely at `while(!true)`.  A while loop will only run when the condition is true.  When you evaluate the condition, do you get true or false?

Comment: Interesting fun fact: No matter what order you specify members in the member initializer list in the constructor, the members will still be initialized in the order they are declared in the class definition. I don't think this is going to bite you here, but I can't build your code to find out, either.  Keyboard stuff is missing.

Comment: @NathanOliver noted, just changed the code in my IDE using an external boolean for the while condition.

Comment: @user4581301 How should I give grid capacity? Should I declare another vector in my constructor and set it equal to grid? (Also fixed `rand_placement`)
Such as: `std::vector<std::vector<char> > _grid(this->dim); this->grid = _grid;`

Answer (score 1):

```
this->grid[0].push_back(this->wallToken);
```

Pushed items into `grid[0]` before `grid` was allocated any storage. There is no `grid[0]` to safely invoke `push_back` on.

Possible Solution:

Preallocate everything in the member initializer.

```
Maze::Maze(int newDim,
           char _avatarToken,
           char _emptyToken,
           char _wallToken,
           char _exitToken,
           char _stairsUpToken,
           char _stairsDownToken,
           char _bossToken) : avatarToken(_avatarToken),
                              emptyToken(_emptyToken),
                              wallToken(_wallToken),
                              exitToken(_exitToken),
                              stairsUpToken(_stairsUpToken),
                              stairsDownToken(_stairsDownToken),
                              bossToken(_bossToken),    
                              dim(newDim), // moved
                              grid(dim, std::vector<char>(dim)) //added
```

and then use operator `[]` instead of pushing characters into the maze. Eg

```
for(int i = 0; i < this->dim; i++)
    this->grid[0][i] = this->wallToken;
```

Thinking on it a bit more,

```
grid(dim, std::vector<char>(dim, _wallToken))
```

will eliminate the need for the loops used to set the bounding walls by initializing every space in the grid as a wall. Save you a bit of work.

Also keep an eye on

```
int rand_placement = rand() % this->dim + 1;
```

`rand_placement` can equal `dim` and the `vector`s are only valid 0 to dim-1. that makes

```
this->grid[rand_placement][0] = this->exitToken;
```

and others write out of bounds.

Comment: I'm having difficulties initializing `grid` in the constructor implementation. I am writing it as `grid(dim, std::vector<char>(dim));` in the first line of my constructor, but I am getting the error `Type 'std::vector<std::vector<char> >' does not provide a call operator`.